# Angular ngFor gives an error in svg, even though it compiles

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, ngfor

I'm trying to make a recursion of lines to make a graph, but there is a strange error in the console, even though it works on node. Here us the template:

```
<svg height = "200" width = "300">
    <g *ngFor = "let node of nodes; let i = index; let last = last;">
      <line 
        [attr.x1] = nodes[i].x
        [attr.y1] = nodes[i].y
        [attr.x2] = nodes[i+1].x
        [attr.y2] = nodes[i+1].y
      />
      <line *ngIf = last
        [attr.x1] = nodes[i].x
        [attr.y1] = nodes[i].y
        [attr.x2] = nodes[i].x
        [attr.y2] = nodes[i].y
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Here is the TypeScript:

```
export class VisitsGraphComponent implements OnInit {
  nodes = [
    { x: 0, y: 0 },
    { x: 40, y: 120 },
    { x: 80, y: 80 },
    { x: 120, y: 90 },
    { x: 160, y: 40 }
  ]
  ngOnInit():void {

  }
}
```

I've tried to use simply the node.x and put it in the ngOnInit(), but the exact same error:

```
Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the last item your nodes array you're still trying to reach nodes[i+1] but there isn't an element, so it will throw error. Just try ngif else block or nodes[i+1]?.x

Comment: Thank you Talha! A tiny adjustment though, instead I did:
```
<line *ngFor = "let node of nodes; let i = index;"
      [attr.x1] = nodes[i-1]?.x
      [attr.y1] = nodes[i-1]?.y
      [attr.x2] = nodes[i].x
      [attr.y2] = nodes[i].y
    />
```
Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

You Bind wrong data
Change  `nodes[i].x` to > `node[i].x`
So try to implement this html file

**.html**

```
<svg height = "200" width = "300">
<g *ngFor = "let node of nodes; let i = index; let last = last;">
  <line 
    [attr.x1] = node[i].x
    [attr.y1] = node[i].y
    [attr.x2] = node[i+1].x
    [attr.y2] = node[i+1].y
  />
  <line *ngIf = last
    [attr.x1] = node[i].x
    [attr.y1] = node[i].y
    [attr.x2] = node[i].x
    [attr.y2] = node[i].y
  />
</g>
```

Comment: nodes is an array node is an object you can't use node[i].